# C# & WPF : How to update an in-code declared textbox height on textbox content change?

Tags: wpf, events, textbox

I'm fairly new to C#, I'm on a C# & Wpf course.
Here my teacher has told us to inherit from UserControls and create a wpf control library of our own. In order for us to create a simple UML Editor, and right now I'm working on a Class Control.

The visual representation of a class as seen here: http://www.softwarefactories.com/ScreenShots/CD-1.JPG

Now, to make things easy for the end user and me as the developer, the fields contained
in the class control contain editable textboxes. The fields can dynamically be added to the
control, for instance if the class doesn't have any member variables, it won't need a "property" field, and if the user would like to add a "description", he/she may do so easily.

That part is done, but right now the TextBoxes don't adapt in size when edited;
the user can add a line, but it won't resize the textbox.

What I want to do is to create an eventhandler of some sort, and have a function
run whenever the user changes the content of the textbox.

-How is this done?

Comment: how did you add the textbox exactly? AFAIK as long as the textbox's height and the container's height are not set then it will resize the textbox automatically.

Comment: I just tried commenting the line where i set the height of the textbox, but it just stays the same.

The textboxes title_textbox and details_textbox are members of my field class, which is inherited from the Canvas class.
Thus, they are not defined in xml initially, but rather created run-time.

the details_textbox has its .AcceptsReturn property set to true.
thanks so far, dnr3. :)

Comment: how about the container of the textbox? did you set its height?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you were absolutely right it's just that I handled the layout wrong further up in the 
code. Anyway, it uses only a constant set of textboxes, so i just defined those in xml and
set the height to auto like it should be. In a stackpanel, they align neatly on top of oneanother. Thanks for your help, dnr3!